# Spring integration TCP server push to client

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to implement a TCP server which basicliy should open a socket as part of handshake with a client .

after socket is open server need to keep the socket open ,  and be able to push a message from the server to the client via the open socket

I look on some spring integration examples but not sure that examples I saw are actully a reference to my requiremnt .

1 .does spring integration tcp has a this ability to keep open socket and send a message from server to client ?

2. the server should support as well incoming requests
3. client side implemenatation is a mock written as a simple Tcp java client

Thanks!
Nir

here context configuration

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server"
                               type="server"
                               port="5679"
                               host="localhost"
                               single-use="false"
                               deserializer="javaDeserializer"
                               serializer="javaSerializer" />



<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundServer"
                                    channel="inloop"
                                    connection-factory="server" client-mode="false"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundServer"
                                     channel="outloop"
                                     connection-factory="server" client-mode="false"/>


<channel id="inloop"/>
<channel id="outloop"/>
```

on the server side I use

```
outputchanel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("HI World from server16\n",header));
```

and on the client side read push message with

```
 BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
    while ((serverResponse = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
      _logger.info("RESPONSE FROM SERVER::"+serverResponse);
    }
```

the client side is a java base tcp client not configure with spring integration , this is a mock client for future integration

for support echo server for a request with byte array not terminate with '\n' , I extend AbstractByteArraySerializer , and override deserialize

```
 public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    _Logger.trace("start deserialize");
    byte[] result;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[getMaxMessageSize()];
        int numOfBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        result = copyToSizedArray(buffer, numOfBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        _Logger.error("Exception on deserialize tcp inbound stream ", e);
        //publishEvent(e, , n);
        throw e;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [collaborating channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters) for completely arbitrary messaging between peers.

See [TCP Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).

The tcp inbound channel adapter (actually the connection factory) will publish a `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` when the client connects.

You can use an `ApplicationListener` to receive these events.

The event contains a `connectionId`. You can then start sending messages to a tcp outbound channel adapter with this `connectionId` in the header named `ip_connectionId` (`IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID`).

Inbound messages (if any) from the client received by the inbound adapter will have the same value in the header.

Simply configure a server connection factory and configure both adapters to use it.

If the server has to open the socket, use `client-mode="true"` and inject a client connection factory.

Comment: Thanks Gary make some progress - succeeded to do exactly what you advice and now working  , but one minor thing the client which get  the push message print some 'gibrish' like  RESPONSE FROM SERVER::�� t HI World from server

Comment: Which serializer are you using? Can you show your connection factory configuration? (Edit the question, don't try to post it as a comment).

Comment: when I use DefaultDeserializer get 'gibrish' , but when I use ByteArrayCrLfSerializer push message on client side without 'gibrish'

Comment: The "gibberish" is because you are using java serialization, which puts information in the stream about how to create the object on the other side; in this case the object is a simple `String`, but it still has the metadata. The `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` adds `\r\n` to the end (and expects the same on inbound and strips them off). The `ByteArrayLfSerializer` just uses `\n`. I suggest you use that one and you don't need to add the `\n` yourself: `"HI World from server16"` - the serializer will add the `\n`.

Comment: can I implement a server that can work like echo server (request/response)  + server that knows to push messages from server (events messages) to the client  ?

Comment: Yes; you can handle both types of messaging, even over the same socket. Simply use the collaborating adapters as I described above; they support completely arbitrary messaging; you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! , make some progress - currently the client I integrated with send a byte array to the server , byte array without termination digit '\n' do I have an option to have some interceptor to add the terminator digit before the execution of the serializer , currently I use ByteArrayLfSerializer

Comment: No; TCP is a streaming protocol there is no way to do what you want on the server side - the packets might get chopped up before delivery so the server can never tell when a "message" is complete. You really have to have the client add something (like `\n`) to the end or use some other mechanism to designate what a message looks like. If you can tell that inherently from the data, then you need a custom deserializer.

Comment: inorder to support push server to client I need ip_connectionId , can I get this value not via the TcpConnectionOpenEvent , but just using some API to get the current open connection id ?

Comment: `connectionFactory.getOpenConnectionIds()` will return a collection of open connection ids.