# Spring Integration Gateway VS Adapters

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

Hello I am new on spring integration

I checked examples for Spring Integration dynamic routing. Finally ı found it in here

[Dynamic TCP Client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client)

In here there were lines

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp.input")
public interface TcpClientGateway {
    byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port);
}

private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
        String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
        Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
        Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
        String hostPort = host + port;

        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(handler);
        IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                this.flowContext.registration(flow)
                        .addBean(cf)
                        .id(hostPort + ".flow")
                        .register();
        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
        this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
        return inputChannel;
    }
```

but i changed it with

```
private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
    String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
    Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
    Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
    String hostPort = host + port;

    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    cf.setLeaveOpen(true);
    //cf.setSingleUse(true);

    ByteArrayCrLfSerializer  byteArrayCrLfSerializer =new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    byteArrayCrLfSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(1048576);

    cf.setSerializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);
    cf.setDeserializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);

    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(cf);

    IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(tcpOutboundGateway);

    IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
        this.flowContext.registration(flow)
            .addBean(cf)
            .id(hostPort + ".flow")
            .register();
    MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();

    this.subFlows.put(hostPort, inputChannel);
    return inputChannel;
}
```

to work with request/response architecture. It really works fine because it provides dynamic routing with out creating tcp clients by hand.

At this point i need some help to improve my scenario. My scenario is like that;

Client sends a message to Server and receive that message's response from server but then server needs to send arbitrary messages to that client (it is like GPS location update information). When server starts to send these messages to client generates error messages like below

> ERROR 54816 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for ::58628:62fd67b6-af2d-42f1-9c4d-d232fbe9c8ca

I checked spring integration document and noticed that Gateways is working only with request/response so i learned that i should use adapters but i do not know how should i use adapters with dynamic tcp client.

here ı found similar topics and some responses but could not reach my goal or found example to combine solutions.

[Spring Integration TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667403/spring-integration-tcp)
[Spring integration TCP server push to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902543/spring-integration-tcp-server-push-to-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to register two flows; one for input; one for output - the problem is correlating the response for the reply, and routing the arbitrary messages to some place other than the gateway.

I updated the sample for this use case [on this branch](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/so62702192/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client).

You can see the changes in the last commit on that branch; most of the changes were to simulate your server side.

On the client side, we simply register two flows and use a `@ServiceActivator` method to get the inbound messages; you can identify which server they come from via the connection id.

Comment: Really thank you Gary, i am looking forward your support

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a branch where I updated the sample.

Comment: Let me check from github and try to apply your solution in to my scenario. I will provide my detailed feedback as soon as i finalized my demo. BR and Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Gary, i proceed and apply your suggestion it seems that now i can receive arbitrary message but i am a bit confused usage of  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp") because previously there was byte[] send(...) method in interface so response was returning to caller by itself but now i have only one method that is called @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp") receiver (...) so i could not return result message to caller service. ı am not sure if i can express.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell

i mean i have there were two lines
 `byte[] result = toTCP.send(data1, host1, portX)` in ServiceA and
 `byte[] result = toTCP.send(data2, host2, portY)` in ServiceB and there may be other toTCP.send in another ServiceX in future...

but now scenario is a bit changed there are still toTcp.send blocks in ServiceA and ServiceB but i have one `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp") ...receiver(...)` so i could not correlate.

Comment: Inn this scenario, the responses come back asynchronously; you can't block in a gateway waiting for the first response; the framework has no way to correlate the response to a request. (It can be done, by adding some logic in the service activator, but it's a bit involved, so it's easier if you can just handle the responses asynchronously).

Comment: Thank you Garry, after your suggestion i checked previous questions and open another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715732/is-it-possible-to-use-tcpsendingmessagehandler-and-tcpouboundgateway-according-t) about it and i found that someone was asking about extending TcpOutboundGateway in this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021319/how-to-extend-tcp-outbound-gateway-to-just-receive-messages-in-spring-integratio?rq=1)  to support req/response and taking only messages from server. Do you think that it can help my scenario ?

Comment: Yes; something like that would work for your use case, if you can tell the difference between the initial reply and the other messages that come later - I didn't remember that question (it was 3 years ago). Given that you are not the first to ask how to do this, we should look at doing something in the framework; please open a new feature issue on GitHub if you want me to explore that.

Comment: Ok, I will wrap up my notes and open a new feature for this functionality

Comment: Hi Garry,  here is the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3326) for feature request